# Change content Real-time - meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have small app (My first Meteor App), where I want add changing real-time content. So, my code looks like this

collection

```
Content = new Meteor.Collection('content');
```

client

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.subscribe('content');

  Template.contentTpl.events({
    'keyup #content': function (e) {
      if (!Content.find({_conId: / some id from session / }).count()) {
        Content.insert({text: e.target.value, _conId: / some id from session / });
      } else {
        Content.update({_conId: / some id from session / }, {text: e.target.value});
      } 
    }
  });

  Template.contentTpl.content = function () {
    return Content.findOne({});
  };
}

<template name="contentTpl">
  <textarea id="content" rows="10" cols="100">{{content.text}}</textarea>
</template>
```

and server

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('content', function () {
    return Content.find();
  });
}
```

But when I open this app in two different browser I see the following, when I'm typing in the first browser - content changing in another browser but when I'm typing in another browser in first browser nothing happens. How I can add changing realtime in meteor ? Should I use somethin like socket.io ?

p.s. In docs I found observe method, but I don't quite understand how to use it to change the property and not for all collection.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

From the Meteor [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve):

> By default, new Meteor apps automatically include the preserve-inputs
>   package. This preserves all elements of type input, textarea, button,
>   select, and option that have unique id attributes or that have name
>   attributes that are unique within an enclosing element with an id
>   attribute. To turn off this default behavior, simply remove the
>   preserve-inputs package.

So once you typed in the textarea in the first browser the text won't change even though `content.text` changes as triggered by the change in the other browser.

You may observe that reactivity is correctly working by putting the handlebars expression `{{content.text}}` outside the textarea, like so:

```
<template name="contentTpl">
  <textarea id="content" rows="10" cols="100">{{content.text}}</textarea>
  <p>
  {{content.text}}
</template>
```

To update the text in the textarea you can remove the `preserve-inputs` package by executing:

```
meteor remove preserve-inputs
```